# AWS PowerShell Error trying to use Substring() going through a $File array

Tags: powershell, amazon-s3, substring

Everything works except the Substring(). I want to use the left 10 bytes of the file name for the folder name to save the files in.

Error Msg:
Method invocation failed because [System.IO.FileInfo] does not contain a method
named 'Substring'.

```
PowerShell code:
$Filter = "*.SCNX"
$files = @(get-childitem  -path $OutBoxPath -filter $filter)
Write-Host 'File Count? ' $Files.count
foreach ($file in $files) {
Write-Host 'File ' $File
Write-Host $File.Substring(0,10)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$File.Name` property to get the file name. `System.IO.FileInfo` is a class from .NET Framework and you can read about it in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Bang! one work and it's fixed.  Many thanks. Now... Do you know how I can mark this as the answer here?  40 years of programming but I'm new at PowerShell and new at Stackoverflow.

Comment: I'm glad that I helped :) There should be a greyed out check mark next to my answer

Comment: If you need information about Powershell then maybe you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/01-getting-started?view=powershell-7). There are also ["About"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about?view=powershell-7) articles which can be helpful. I don't know much about Powershell, mostly I work with .NET stuff.